# Dispose object instance(s) on application exit/crash with WPF / Prism

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism, dryioc

I'm using the prism framework for my WPF application with DryIoc, but maybe I don't quite understand some of it's uses. (Self-taught) or best practises.

I have a class library (`MyLibrary`) that follows a disposable pattern as it needs to do some clean-up.
I have a module that uses `MyLibrary` in its view model.

If the application is closed or even on an application crash, I would like to call dispose on this library, just in case it isn't already disposed of correctly at this time (otherwise it will leave third party apps open in the background)

There is currently only 1 instance, but could be more than 1 in the future.

So far, this is what I have come up with:

When my view model first requires `MyLibrary` it will register an instance, like so:

`this.ce.RegisterInstance<MyLibrary>(this.myLibrary, "MyLibraryName");` where `ce` is `Prism.Ioc.IContainerExtension`
and then in the `protected override void OnExit(ExitEventArgs e)` method in my App.xaml.cs I will do: `this.Container.Resolve<MyLibrary>("MyLibraryName")?.Dispose();`

This successfully disposes my library object (and closes the 3rd party windows as i expect it to), however, it just seems a bit off to me (Code smell?)

Is there a better way to do it? I don't feel like the App.xaml.cs should have to know about the instance name that my module's view model came up with for example. Is there a way to just call Dispose on all `MyLibrary` types in the container without the name string?

I was hoping I could iterate over all `MyLibrary`s in the container and call Dispose?
If there isn't a better way then I'm ok with it I suppose.

But just as important: How can I attempt to call Dispose in a similar fashion on any unhandled exceptions that would otherwise crash the app? Can I access the container somehow and dispose of any `MyLibrary`s?
I wouldn't intend to try and save the app from crashing, just make sure that `MyLibrary` calls its Dispose method.

---

**Comment response (Too many characters):**

Click UI button> Delegate command> code written in method in VM.
The Library has an overhead to start up(sign in).

There are multiple input steps on the UI that requires use of the library.
Wrapping it in a `using` at each stage (button click) is not impossible, but it is inefficient because of the libraries startup overhead.

I want to:

```
- Instantiate library

- User inputs data, library does work, returns results, requires more input etc

- Several more of these data input stages / library work / results

- Dispose
```

Problem:

```
- User exits application before library object is disposed

- How/Where to dispose?
```

Attempted solution:

```
- Use the container so that i can dispose in App.xaml.cs `OnExit`

- This solution works, but feels incorrect?
```

Question: What can I do better/different in this situation?
Additional question: How do I handle disposing this upon a fatal crash in a prism app?

It's important that it gets disposed of so that instances of 3rd party apps that the library utilises are not left running in the background.

Comment: _What do you want to do?_ Why does a view model register a library? Where does the library instance come from in the first place?

Comment: Too many characters for comment to try explain. See Comment response in edit. @Haukinger

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I changed it to register an instance in app.xaml.cs now and I can avoid the `.Resolve` call. Would you do it like this? If not then how? When it was registered as a singleton I had no idea how to get it in `OnExit` without the `.Resolve`

Cut-down/simplified example of my app.xaml.cs now:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public partial class App
    {
        public App()
        {
            // Crash handling
            this.Dispatcher.UnhandledException += this.OnDispatcherUnhandledException;
        }
    
        // My library provider that contains a dictionary of library instances.
        public IMyProvider MyProvider { get; set; } = new MyProvider();

        // Dispose provider on crash
        public void OnDispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
            this.MyProvider.Dispose();
            MessageBox.Show("Unhandled exception occurred: \n" + e.Exception.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
        }

        protected override Window CreateShell()
        {
            return this.Container.Resolve<MainWindow>();
        }

        // Register as an instance?
        protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
        {
            containerRegistry.RegisterInstance<IMyProvider>(this.MyProvider);
        }

        protected override void ConfigureModuleCatalog(IModuleCatalog moduleCatalog)
        {
            // Add modules here...
        }

        protected override void OnExit(ExitEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnExit(e);

            // Dispose my provider (and all contained instances in its dictionary)
            this.MyProvider.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Comment character limit preventing me from writing too much again.

@Haukinger: tl;dr: You got me on the right track.

I didn't quite follow your example exactly to the letter (not using Lazy, library doesnt have an interface), but you got me on the right track.
Overall, I'm struggling to wrap my head around: DI, IoC, Interfaces and how they all relate.

Your line about abusing the container got me to look a little closer at it.
First, I removed all instances of `containerExtension.resolve` from view models and instead injected into the constructor as it should have always been.

I created a provider similar to what you suggested and a provider interface for my library.
The provider implementation keeps a dictionary of named library instances in case I require multiple.
I still call `this.Container.Resolve<IMyProvider>().Dispose();` in the application's `OnExit` but it feels better because I don't have to name an instance any more.
Just having a provider interface still doesn't stop anyone from new-ing up library instances themselves though?

Library interface is registered like so:
`containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<IMyProvider, MyProvider>();`

Other than my library:
I'm currently registering a few application wide instances for a few things like application theme in the container like so: `containerRegistry.RegisterInstance<MyThing>(this.MyThing);`
Still not using interfaces here. Still trying to understand them, but an application wide instance for theme in the container is working just fine.

From examples I've seen where `IAnimal` interface can have a `Dog` and a `Cat` implementation, my objects don't have multiple implementation requirements. (Besides unit testing which I'm yet to attempt to learn and I assume I will benefit from interfaces in this situation) I just need access to some things from different modules/assemblies and was using the container to do so.

One of my biggest problems was that I have parameters to construct some instances like my library and the parameters are not known until run time, so I couldn't register an instance in app.xaml.cs when the app starts.

If I have to construct something with parameters that are only known at runtime (credentials for example) Do I need to follow a sort of factory pattern with an interface to be able to register them or am I missing something?
I guess I could register an instance with the container extension at the time they get created (in assembly A's view model A)? but then I would need to use `.Resolve` later if I want them in a different module (Assembly B's view model X)?
Which doesn't feel right, and creating a factory and a factory interface for a simple credentials object feels overkill?

I think I'm just not fully understanding interfaces, as examples I've seen often dont have parameters for the implementation or they focus on discussing the benefits of different implementations when I will only have 1 implementation.
Or examples have nothing to do with IoC or DI.

As far as handling disposing on application crash event I did the following:

```
public App()
{
    this.Dispatcher.UnhandledException += this.OnDispatcherUnhandledException;
}

public void OnDispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    // Dispose provider
    this.Container.Resolve<IMyProvider>().Dispose();

    // Unhandled exception messagebox:
    MessageBox.Show("Unhandled exception occurred: \n" + e.Exception.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
}
```

I'm still tearing my hair out over interfaces / factory pattern / DI / Ioc / General design, but you got me on the right track.
I'm injecting stuff into constructors better, I can manage my library instances with the provider and dispose on exit and on crash is working.

Thanks.

Comment: You should never ever call `Resolve`, that is, at least 99,9% of the time. There are use cases where calling it is actually a good idea, but they are rare. You want your single, first call to do all the work ( `Resolve<MainWindowViewModel>`), none of your code should even be aware that you're using a container.

Comment: @Haukinger, I added a new answer with a Cut-down/simplified example of my app.xaml.cs that removes the resolve call by instead registering an instance of ```MyProvider``` to ```IMyProvider```, If this isn't correct then I'm completely lost as to how to achieve what I want (correctly).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you do not try to abuse the container here.

Instead, create a manager for your library yourself and clean that one up at shutdown:

```
public interface ILibraryProvider : IDisposable
{
    ILibrary GetLibrary();
}

internal class LibraryProvider : ILibraryProvider
{
    public LibraryProvider( Lazy<ILibrary> library )
    {
        _library = library;
    }

    #region ILibraryProvider
    public ILibrary GetLibrary() => _library.Value;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_library.IsValueCreated)
            _library.Value.Dispose();
    }
    #endregion

    #region private
    private readonly Lazy<ILibrary> _library;
    #endregion
}
```

In `Application.OnExit`, dispose the `LibraryManager`.

If you need multiple, distinct libraries, add a string parameter to `Get`, inject a `Func` instead of a `Lazy` and store the instances in a `Dictionary`.